# How do I know the number of elements in each cluster?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I would like to know how do I find out the number of elements it has in each cluster. I insertd an executable code below. From the plot I know that cluster 1 has 8 properties, cluster 2 has 4 properties and cluster 3 has 7 properties. But if I have 200 properties, for example, it will be confusing to look at the plot. Is there a function that I can do this more directly?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)


df<-structure(list(Propertie = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.9, -23.5, -23.4, -23.6,-23.9, -23.2, -23.5, -23.8, -23.7, -23.8, -23.9, -23.4, -23.9, 
                                                                                                 -23.9, -23.2, -23.3, -23.7, -23.8), 
                    Longitude = c(-49.1, -49.3,-49.4, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7,-49.2, -49.5, -49.8, -49.5, -49.3, -49.3, -49.2, -49.5), 
                    Waste = c(526,350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364,175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L)) 

#clusters
coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k=3) 
df$cluster <- clusters 
plot(fit.average,hang=-1,cex=.8,main="Average Linkage Clustering")
rect.hclust(fit.average,k=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
table(clusters)
```

If you want to extract the values ​​in a vector

```r
as.numeric(table(clusters))
```

when you use `cutree` function, this generates an integer vector marking elements `1` through `n`, where `n` is the number of clusters you set. The `table` function counts the elements belonging to each cluster

Comment: Thanks so much Leonardo! =D